# Can an azure active directory domain be federated with an openid connect IdP like identityserver and does this support Azure AD Join

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid, identityserver4, federated-identity

We currently have a solution where azure ad domains are federated with our ADFS server. This solution uses the WS-Trust and WS-fed protocols. Ws-fed is used for the passive auth flow in the browser, WS-Trust (the usernamemixed endpoint) is used for AAD joined windows 10 devices.

Unfortunately for us, ADFS doen not provide us with all the customization options that we need. Therefore we are looking in to moving to a custom IdP. IdentityServer looks like a good fit. Unfortunately the last version of IdentityServer to support WS-Trust is identityServer2. I'm currently trying to get this to work, but I would much prefer to leave the WS-* protocol behind completely and move to openid connect.

One thing I noticed during my experiments is that the powershell command `Get-MsolDomainFederationSettings` shows a field `OpenIdConnectDiscoveryEndpoint`. Does that mean that I can federate my azure domain with openid connect?

Another thing that I noticed is that the azure ad joined windows 10 machine was unexpectedly calling an open id discovery endpoint on my identityserver. That gave a 404 because I don't have it configured. But just the fact that it was called leads me to hope that AAD join could support openid connect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Both ADFS (2016) Azure AD support OpenID Connect and you can certainly use them as the ultimate IdP in an IDS4 implementation.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want to use IDS4 as the IdP to which I federate my AAD domain. This shoud,also support login from Azure AD joined windows 10 devices.

Comment: In that case I think you're out of luck

Comment: @MarkHasper, I'm in a similar situation. Did you make any progress on this matter?

Comment: @Merijn, I couldn't find any more information about azure ad join and open id so in the end we went with a custom solution using ws-fed and ws-trust. We got a lot of inspiration from the source of identity server 3. I'm still not completely happy with this, so if you find more info about aad join and openid then please let me know. If you go the ws-trust route, you can always let me know and I'll try to help you out with some of our solution. Good luck.